# How to set paths in the .pro file for Windows?

Tags: qt, qmake

I tried to run a Qt project with `qmake`. My `win32` section in the `.pro` file looks like this:

```
win32 {
    DEFINES +=GIT_BIN=C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git  
    DEFINES += GIT_REVISION=C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git rev-parse --short 
    HEAD  
    DEFINES += GIT_REVISION_ATOOLS='\"$$system('C:\Program 
    Files\Git\bin\git' 
    rev-parse --short HEAD)\"'  
    DEFINES += _USE_MATH_DEFINES  
    DEFINES += NOMINMAX  
    SIMCONNECT=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Games\Microsoft Flight 
    SimulatorX\WidevieW  
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\Program Files\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4 SDK 
    4.3.29.25520\inc\SimConnect  
    LIBS+=C:\Program Files\Lockheed Martin\Prepar3D v4 SDK
    4.3.29.25520\lib\SimConnect\SimConnect.lib
}
```

But I get the error:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

How to fix this?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git` path contains spaces. You have to enclose it with quotes like `DEFINES +=GIT_BIN="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git"`

Comment: Thank you @vahancho I tried that but it still threw the same error

Comment: Make sure you use "(re)run qmake" after modifying any .pro or .pri file. A (re)build will run the makefile generated in the qmake step. Only a (re)run of qmake will update the makefile(s) with your corrected path.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error at the [system(command[, mode[, stsvar]])](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command-mode-stsvar) replace function.

Add escaped quotes, i.e. `\"`, around `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git` to fix it:

```
DEFINES += GIT_REVISION_ATOOLS='\"$$system(\"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git\" rev-parse --short HEAD)\"'
```

Quotes around the other paths are not required.

Comment: i had to DEFINES += GIT_REVISION_ATOOLS='\\"$$system('..\..\Progra~1\Git\bin\git' rev-parse --short HEAD)\\"'

Comment: @MangalaG, in my case with this correction your code compiles without errors.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to run it by using your correction but get the error of undefined macro GIT_REVISION_ATOOLS. changing it back to what i have shared in the comment earlier works